# JAVA добавить в исключения брандмауэра

Tags: java

Есть ли способ, средствами JAVA добавить мою программу в исключения брандмауэра. Чтобы последний не блокировал работу приложения? то есть, при запуске, предлагать пользователю добавить это исключение, чтобы ему не приходилось это делать руками?

Comment: Очень сомневаюсь. Тогда исчезает весь смысл брандмауэра, если любая программа-злоумышленник может саму себя добавить в исключение и запуститься

Comment: @Антон Мухин  не сама себя, а с согласия пользователя. я точно видел похожее в какой-то программе, но она была написана не на java